# Git Tag Points to Wrong Commit ID

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

So currently I have a simple Jenkins job that fetches origin, creates a tag, and pushes the tag. This Jenkins job is run once a week and the date ran is part of the tag name. I do these weekly tags to make git patches and merge different baselines together if desired for core changes (all this stuff happens in separate Jenkins jobs and I doubt is relevant). This done in around 10 repos, but my issue only happens in one repo.

In the repo with the issue, this job has now been running for roughly 3 years and has around 160 tags of these tags (around 380 tags total in the repo). Recently, about once every 3-4 months (4 times in 2020 from September to December), there have been issues with the tags where they point to a commit from 3.75 years ago (every messed up tag points to the same commit ID). This repo * **should** * be the same as the other 9 repos that do not have this issue.

I cannot replicate this as it does not happen often but any ideas as to why this might be happening or ways to prevent it from happening again please let me know!

Shell code from the Jenkins job (git calls repeat in loop for each repo):

```
TODAY=$(date +'%Y%m%d)

git fetch origin && git tag DIFFS_$TODAY && git push origin DIFFS_$TODAY
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `git pull` instead of `git fetch`?

Comment: Or `git tag DIFFS_$Today origin/main` to explicitly tag the current commit on origin/main after fetch.

Comment: In the preceding Jenkins jobs to this I thought there was a `git pull` but actually there is a `git fetch` and then the `origin/main` is specified on the patch. Apparently we used `git fetch` to save time, so to continue with that design I think I will try to following @jessehouwing suggestion. Hopefully that works and I am not back to square one in 2 months or whenever it fails again. Thank you both, I think both are good suggestions/edits/improvements!

Comment: Note that using `git fetch` does not merely save *time*, it also saves running the second command that `git pull` runs, and that second command can *fail* (in some cases). So it avoids this failure possibility, and hence seems like an even better idea. :-) (`pull` = *run two commands* with the first one being `git fetch` and the second defaulting to `git merge`, but you can choose which second command to use.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform `git fetch`, the new commits on the remote are added to your local repo, but the `HEAD` isn't advanced to that latest commit, it still points to the commit the repo was looking at when the last pull/reset/commit has taken place.

When you perform `git pull`, the latest commits are `fetch`ed and then git will try to advance to the latest version. Depending on the state of your local repo & config it may do one of the following:

- fast-forward
- merge
- rebase

Each of these can fail, hence `pull` is a bit of a dangerous option. A safer option, if you know you want exactly the changes on origin, is to `fetch`, then `reset --hard`. That will not try to do any merges and forces a fast-forward.

If all you want, is to set a tag, you don't even need the local working directory to reflect the remote changes. After fetching you can specify you want to `tag origin/main`

```
 git fetch origin/main
 git tag DIFFS_$TODAY origin/main
 git push --tags DIFFS_$TODAY
```

But there is an even simpler way (or at least faster), you can push the tag without having to create it locally, but you still have to fetch the changes:

```
 git push origin origin/main:refs/tags/DIFFS_$TODAY
```

Comment: So far so good with this method, thank you!